# Regex with decimal points

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a pattern for an input that can accept the following, but I am not very good with regex. Can someone help me with making a regex for the following values.

```
1
.25
0.25
```

Comment: @anubhava: Won't work for the second example.

Comment: @chris85: Beat me by milliseconds  :)

Comment: @Jan yeee haw, http://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Speedy-Gonzales.jpg

Comment: @chris85: What about `.25.23` with your expression?

Comment: @chris85: http://img.movieboom.biz/movie/screen/129457/2.jpg

Comment: `^.*$` accepts all your examples - so does `^(1|0?\.25)$`, so I guess you need to clarify a bit more clearly what exactly should match - and what * shouldn't*  match.

Comment: If you're not very good with regex, try something basic like `1|.25|0.25` that's a start, but to do nothing is not appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess at an expression to would work for you would be:

```
^(\.\d+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$
```

The `|` is an or. 
The `^` is the start of the string.
 The `$` is the end.
 The `\.` is a literal `.`.
 The `\d` is a number.
 The `+` is a quantifier meaning one or more of the previous character/group.
The `?` makes the previous group/character optional.

So `\.\d+` is a `.` then any number of numbers. Then `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` is a number followed by optional decimals values.

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/uG2tT4/1

The `m` and/or `g` modifier might be needed depending on where you are using this. Also the `\d` might need to be converted to the number character class `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

From 'universal regular expression' (all implementations in all languages), it will be safe to use
`\d*\.\d*`

This is simply broken down to

```
\d* = Match for 0 or more digits at the beginning
\.  = After that match for a period (notice that we escaped the period.
        Not escaping the period has a different meaning altogether.)
\d* = Match for another set of one or more digits
```

This seeks to simplify regular expressions though it may not be the most efficient, especially if it is for a large set

For tutorials on regular expressions, I can suggest [`RegularExpressions.info`](http://www.regular-expressions.info) or Check out Derek Banas' video tutorials on regular expressions on Youtube

Comment: `.` would be valid with that expression. `\d` is not available in all languages.

Comment: If \d is not available in all languages, then you could go for  [0,9]. BTW i found this cool site www.regexone.com where you can test your regular expressions

Comment: In addition to "." passing when it shouldn't, "1" fails when it should pass.